# simple javascript regex question

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I match the following pattern?

"anything123.anythingelse"

Alphanum of any length, with exactly 1 "." in the middle, and then alphanum of any length?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

That would then be `/[a-z0-9]+\.[a-z0-9]+/i`. The `/i` is the case insensitive modifier.

```
var match = /[a-z0-9]+\.[a-z0-9]+/i.test(string);
alert(match); // true or false.
```

If you can allow underscores, this can be done shorter: `/\w+\.\w+/`.  The `\w` is the same as `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`.

**See also**: http://www.regular-expressions.info

Comment: and `[\w]` is the same as `\w` ;)

Comment: if the alphanumeric parts can be zero length, it'd be a * instead of a + in both cases